# Generating APK with all dynamic features

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-app-bundle, dynamic-feature

I have added a **dynamic feature module** to my project and everything works fine when trying on emulator or direct run on a device (using the run button) but when I try to generate a APK using command line (`:app:assembleRelease`) the dynamic feature modules wont be included in the final APK and it's missing. I know I can create a Android App Bundle and then create a APK from `.aab` with all the modules. but the question is:

> is there a way to create full apk (all modules such as: Dynamic
>   features included) directly form source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't create full apk directly form source.

You should take 3 steps:

1. Build app bundle:

   `./gradlew clean bundleRelease`
2. Generate one apk by bundletool with switch --mode=universal

   `java -jar bundletool-all-0.10.2.jar build-apks --bundle=app.aab --output=release.apks --ks=release.keystore --ks-pass=pass:xxxxxx --ks-key-alias=xxxxxxkey --key-pass=pass:xxxxxx --mode=universal`
3. Unzip generated file:

   `unzip release.apks`

Answer (score 1):

With the command line, you should use `:app:bundleRelease` which will build an Android App Bundle (.San), then use `bundletool` to generate the APKs and deploy them to the device.

The full documentation can be found here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool

Comment: supporting comment for @Pierre reply by copying the commands from link mentioned.    https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#bundle_build_gradle                                                                   bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
--ks=/MyApp/keystore.jks
--ks-pass=file:/MyApp/keystore.pwd
--ks-key-alias=MyKeyAlias
--key-pass=file:/MyApp/key.pwd                                                                               https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool#generate_apks

Comment: thanks for the answer. what I'm actually looking for is like shortcut from source to APK without first generating AAB then APK.
is there anyway you can think of?

Comment: File a feature request in the Android Gradle Plugin, I think a task exists, but I'm not sure it's exposed or documented.